# why deleting zeros from list not working?

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this

`[0, -1.1030425708011151, -1.1030425708011151, 0, 0, -1.5398884825250256, 0, 1.081186987818438]`

and using this code that always worked for me I'm trying to delete zeros:

`self.observation = self.observation[self.observation != 0]`

but this time it's returning just a scalar => `-1.1030425708011151`

I have no idea why it's not working can someone help me?

Comment: `a = [0, 1, 2, 0, 4]` then `b = [n for n in a if n!=0]` voila `b == [1, 2, 4]`

Comment: The code "that always worked for me" only works with numpy arrays, not Python lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> observation = [0, -1.1030425708011151, -1.1030425708011151, 0, 0, -1.5398884825250256, 0, 1.081186987818438]
>>> observation = [i for i in observation if i != 0]
[-1.1030425708011151,
 -1.1030425708011151,
 -1.5398884825250256,
 1.081186987818438]
```

What happens if you do `observation[observation != 0]` is that first `observation != 0` is evaluated to `True` which is cast to `1` which returns the second element in your list.

Answer (score 1):

Because you this code this code:

```
self.observation = self.observation[self.observation != 0]
```

Getting element with index 1, it do the same as

```
self.observation = self.observation[1]
```

If you want to exclude all zeros you need to do like that:

```
self.observation = [i for i in self.observation if i != 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

`self.observation[self.observation != 0]` will just select the second item on the list. `self.observation != 0` gets coerced from a boolean to an integer (from True to 1).
You need to do a list comprehension

```
self.observation = [i for i in self.observation if i != 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you index a list, it takes integers; so when you do `self.observation != 0` it compares the list with 0 so it returns `true` which is converted to int `1` and so do `self.observation[0]` if you want to construct a list from a condition, you can use list comprehension:

```
self.observation = [obs for obs in self.observation if obs != 0]
```

You can also use filter:

```
self.observation = filter(lambda obs: obs != 0, self.observation)
```